# image not getting displayed on my website

Tags: html, css

I have used the following code to display image:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href=""><img src="images/earth.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
</div>
```

where header's css code is:

```
#header { 
   width: 960px; 
   min-height: 150px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

I am sure that the path is correct.
What can be the problem?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no path in this code.

Comment: You didn't included `background`

Comment: Where is the html code?  Try to give full information so others can help you. Although path is correct,  however your tag name might be abnormal or the placement of the image tag inside the html might be false!

Comment: @user3313660 please update your posted question

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by the code you've supplied in the question. Either the path is wrong (debug it using the developer tools Net tab in your browser) or there is some other CSS causing the problem that you haven't included here.

Comment: everything seems perfect by seeing your code.. check at your side Is image exist or not on the folder or may be the image format coudd be different.

Comment: The image exists and the format is also correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

where do you display the image? can show some more code?

### EDIT

your code is working so I think the address to your image is not correct see JS fiddle

```
<div id="header">
<a href=""><img src="http://s.numrush.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Planet-earth-540x303.jpg" alt="Logo" /></a>
```

```
#header { 
width: 960px; 
min-height: 150px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKTFN/

Comment: <div id="header">
<a href=""><img src="images/monkey-logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
</div> is the html code

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly a comment.

Comment: @robin actually this is not an answer, you can improve your answer by providing a working Demo.

Comment: There was some problem in uploading the file. It seems file has to be uploaded using ftp only.